# How to set a time delay to trigger an upcoming event in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am going to use a time delay to trigger one event. Once one process is completed, one signal is emitted, e.g., `mysignal(int timedelay)`, the receiver of the signal will initiate another process **right when** a period of the specified time `timedelay` is elapsed after the signal is emitted.

Are there some specialized functions to handle this? I note `QThread::sleep()` or `QThread::msleep()` may be suitable to deal such a situation? Are they better than using a QTimer object and setting a signal-slot connection accordingly?

Comment: Similar questions can be found here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480637/how-to-use-qtimer-to-create-a-singleshot-timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480637/how-to-use-qtimer-to-create-a-singleshot-timer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `QThread::sleep()` on the main thread where the Qt event-loop lives since it will block signals, events, etc. Instead use a QTimer that invokes a function whose task is to emit the signal.

Example:

```
#include <QtCore>

class Sender: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    Q_SIGNAL void mysignal(const QString & text);
    void process(){
        /**
         *    process
         */
        int timeout = 1000;
        // send signal after 1000 ms
        QTimer::singleShot(timeout, this, &Sender::send_signal);
    }
private:
    // The only task of this function is to emit the signal
    void send_signal(){
        qDebug()<< "send signal";
        Q_EMIT mysignal("Hello");
    }
};

class Receiver: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    Q_SLOT void myslot(const QString & text){
        qDebug()<< "Received:" << text;
        QCoreApplication::quit();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Sender sender;
    Receiver receiver;
    QObject::connect(&sender, &Sender::mysignal, &receiver, &Receiver::myslot);

    // call process
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &sender, &Sender::process);
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am wonder if you can modify the codes a bit for the purpose to verify the timing accuracy. I need very accurate timing for trigger events.  Thanks!

Comment: @jingweimo, If you are using Qt5, you will want to set QTimer::setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer)